# "uninitialized constant ActiveRecord" on migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

have a problem creating my new table in SqlLite3

I have created this migration using the scaffolding generator:

```
class CreateTimes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :times do |t|
      t.integer :regsite
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamp :added
      t.integer :time
      t.text :note

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :times
  end
end
```

the name of the file is **`20091011203652_create_times.rb`**

When trying to migrate I get this error:

```
>rake db:migrate 
(in C:/...)
rake aborted!
uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.4/lib/rake.rb:2359:in `raw_load_rakefile'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I started adapting from PHP to RoR yesterday, so sorry if it's an obvious answer, but have tried everything I know, but nothing solves it.

Comment: Can you show us your config/environment.rb please? I think you may have removed the activerecord framework.

Comment: What's the output of "gem list --local"?

Comment: Here is the enviroment.rb http://pastie.org/650760 and "gem list --local" http://pastie.org/650759

Comment: Can you try updating rails to the newest version and change your app to that version (In the environment.rb) and tell us if that changes anything?

Comment: It all works with a different table, It's just something with this one which doesn't want to cooperate.

Comment: Oh then my workaround will not help I suppose. Can you try renaming the migration (calling "script/generate migration" again) to make sure it is not a name conflict? And could you also post the content of the model-file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call your table *times* since that would need a model class called `Time` which is a built-in Ruby class. I bet that is the problem. Try changing it to something else and see if that helps.

Comment: I should have thought less about the versions and more about the code ;-)